# Jetson Xavier Entry Level CSI-2 Camera Module

Tags: camera, nvidia, nvidia-jetson, csi

Looking for an entry-level camera module for the Jetson Xavier

Hi,

I have been looking into the Jetson Xavier Development Board which meets my requirements for size and performance. As part of my build I need to add many camera modules, ideally 8-12. Posting on the Nvidia forum I am told to contact their 'preferred suppliers' who mostly specialise in industry ready cameras retailing at circa £300 per unit (I want 12 of them... per unit... that's expensive). My requirements are for object detection and as such I only need a basic standard of image.

The Xavier documentation specifies that their preferred camera connection is CSI-2. My question is: "If anyone has experience with Xavier cameras will any CSI-2 camera suffice or do I need to find one with compatible drivers?"

Thank you

Comment: I am facing the same problem, I am looking for a low cost solution to connect a pi-camera into the AGX Xavier Camera Connector as described at this post: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-can-i-connect-this-camera/140966 Did you find a solution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Kindly look into the below products

https://www.e-consystems.com/nvidia-jetson-camera.asp#xavier-cameras

https://www.e-consystems.com/nvidia-cameras/jetson-agx-xavier-cameras/four-synchronized-4k-cameras.asp

In Xavier, you can connect maximum 6 cameras through CSI-2 MIPI interface. And you can add additional USB3.0 cameras in USB interface. By this way you can match your requirement to connect multiple cameras to Jetson Xavier.